# Multi Business unit creates a duplicate lead in salesforce

Tags: integration, leads, pardot

We have a scenario. We recently configured 4 new Pardot Business Units. All 4 BUs are connected to single salesforce org.

As per the implementation guide, we configured Marketing data sharing, stopped the syncing of "Pardot package fields" in connectors for all BUs and also implemented a custom integration to pull the Pardot package fields in custom object in salesforce.

However, upon testing, we found below behavior :

**Business unit 1**

create a prospect with email 'test@gmail.com'

**Salesforce**

New lead is created in SF with email 'test@gmail.com'

**Business unit 2**

Prospect with same email 'test@gmail.com' is created.

***Expectation*** :
The prospect from Business unit 2 should sync to same salesforce lead.

***Actual*** :
Duplicate SF Lead is getting created.

Can someone please comment if any configuration setting is missed or this is an ideal behavior of the connector?

Thanks

Samir

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is working as intended.  The reason is that BU2 cannot see the Lead that was created by BU1, as Marketing Data Sharing (MDS) is preventing BU2 from seeing the Lead from BU1.

For a Cross Business Unit Implementation (the scenario you are describing), you need to have automation which takes the new Lead in Salesforce, finds a match and merges it.

Comment: Thank you @Adam for your comments. If this is the intended behavior and multi BU supports one-to-one relationship, then why Pardot suggest to stop the syncing of Pardot package fields and implement custom integration?

https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?language=en_US&type=5&release=230&id=release-notes.rn_pardot_sync_multiple_prospects.htm

Comment: When you have a Single Lead/Contact syncing to multiple Pardot Business Units (PBU), each PBU tries to update the same fields on the Salesforce record. This is the reason you turn it off, so that each PBU doesn't fight to have the correct values in SF (also why you have to create your own solution to showing relevant Package Fields in Pardot in a custom object).

Comment: If you have a Single Lead/Contact syncing to a single PBU, then you don't need to turn off the syncing of Pardot Package Fields, as there will never be a conflict (but you will have dupes in SF for a Lead/Contact in multiple PBUs)

Comment: Can we stop the duplicate leads/contact using standard connector configuration?

Comment: I mean you could remove MDS rules and have all Leads/Contacts sync into all PBUs, but likely that's not what you actually want. I'm not 100%, but I think Selective Sync MIGHT be an option still available (just note the use of MDS does disable ObjectChangeLog across all PBUs).

Comment: So, its safe to assume that its a behavior and not a bug and duplicate lead will be created and one-to-one mapping will be there?